# MySQLi Round Rand()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm learning PHP and MySQLi. Working on simple website, and I have problem with Rand() in mysqli.

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=posts.uid WHERE posts.uid=users.user_id and posts.active=1 and catid=6 AND feat=1 AND pid >= Round(  Rand() * ( SELECT Max( pid ) FROM posts )) limit 1
```

This is how I'm selecting posts from database, and show them randomly on website, but the problem is when let's say 2 posts show randomly the 3rd one (refresh) will say there's no post in rows and show nothing, in my case.

```
 if($CountRows==0){ ?> <div class="col-note">No more posts.</div>
   <?php } ?>
```

After I refresh website again it will randomly show one of the posts, and everything is working.

My question is, how to show randomly news without showing note "No more posts". So if there's 2 posts, it should randomly switch from 1st to 2nd always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `ORDER BY RAND()`? It orders the query results randomly

Also use a normal join instead of a left join and remove the ' `posts.uid=users.user_id`'.

Comment: Thank you. I complicated things with this, but I figured out how it's working, but nevermind, I'll use RAND().